# Show that the graph of $y=x^3\sin(\pi/x)$ extends to a smooth arc

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

Here's the problem:

> Let $y(x)$ be a real-valued function defined on the interval $x\in [0,1]$ by means of the equation
>   $$y(x)= \left\{
> \begin{array}{lr}
>        x^3\sin(\frac{\pi}{x}) \;\;\;\mathbb{for}  & x \in (0,1]
>        \\0 \;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\mathbb{for} & x=0
>        \end{array}
>    \right.$$
>
> (a) Show that $z=x+iy(x)$ represent an arc $C$ that intersects the real axis at points $z=\frac{1}{n}$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{Z^+}$, and $z=0$
>
> (b) Verify that the arc $C$ in part (a) is, in fact, a *smooth* arc.

Okay so I figured out part (a). Now, I think I figured out part (b), but am not sure if my logic was valid. Here's the work:

> **Attempted work for (b)**
>
> In order for an arc to be *smooth*, $z'$ must be continuous on $[a,b]$ and non-zero on $(a,b)$. Since $z=x+iy(x)$, differentiating our result on $(0,1]$ will give us 
>   $$z'=1+i(3x^2\sin(\frac{\pi}{x})-\pi x\cos(\frac{\pi}{x}))$$ 
>   Clearly, $x'$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ and non-zero on $(0,1)$ since any value we plug in will just give us $1$. $y'(x)$ is clearly defined for all values NOT $0$, so it is certainly continuous on $(0,1]$. Further, because of the relation between cosine and sine, it follows that $y'$ is non-zero on $(0,1)$ since sine and cosine will never be $0$ at the same time. We wish to show that $y'$ is continuous at $0$.
>
> Suppose that $y' \to 0$ when $x \to 0$. Then given $\epsilon >0$, we wish to show $\exists \delta >0$ s.t $\forall x \in (0,1]$ and 
>   $$|x-0|<\delta \implies |3x^2\sin(\frac{\pi}{x})-\pi x\cos(\frac{\pi}{x})-0|<\epsilon$$
>   Observe that since $|sin(x)| \leq 1$, $|cos(x)| \leq 1$, we can extend this to $|sin(\frac{\pi}{x})|,|cos(\frac{\pi}{x})|$. Thus, observe that
>   $$|3x^2\sin(\frac{\pi}{x})-\pi x\cos(\frac{\pi}{x})| \leq |3x^2\sin(\frac{\pi}{x})|+|-\pi x\cos(\frac{\pi}{x})-0| \leq |3x^2|+\pi|x|$$
>   Since $x>0$, it follows that
>   $$|3x^2|+\pi|x| = 3x^2+\pi x < 3x^2 + 4x = 3x(x+\frac{4}{3})<\epsilon$$
>   $$\impliedby 3x < \frac{\epsilon}{x+\frac{4}{3}}$$
>   And since $x \leq 1$,
>   $$\frac{\epsilon}{x+\frac{4}{3}} \leq \frac{\epsilon}{1+\frac{4}{3}} = \frac{3\epsilon}{7}$$
>   so
>   $$3x<\frac{3\epsilon}{7} \impliedby x=|x-0|< \frac{\epsilon}{7} = \delta$$
>   Thus, given $\epsilon >0$, $\exists \delta=\frac{\epsilon}{7}$ s.t $\forall x\in (0,1]$ and
>   $$|x-0|<\frac{\epsilon}{7} \implies |3x^2\sin(\frac{\pi}{x})-\pi x\cos(\frac{\pi}{x})-0|<\epsilon$$
>   It is clear that $y'(x)$ is continuous at $0$. So $y'(x)$ is continuous on $[0,1]$ $\implies$ our arc is smooth.

So my question: was what I did valid in the proof? Or did I pull some strings that shouldn't have been pulled?

Comment: Oh sorry about that! Thank you for editing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are beginning with "Suppose that $y'\to0$ when $x\to 0$"; but you mean: "First I shall prove that $y'(x)\to0$ when $x\to0$". Then you go on and prove it alright. (Actually it is not necessary to carry out an $\epsilon$-$\delta$ proof. The claim follows immediately using the principle $a(x)b(x)\to0$ when $|a(x)|$ is bounded and $b(x)\to0$.)

But now comes the flaw: In order to prove that $y'$ is continuous at $0$ you have to show that $\lim_{x\to0}y'(x)=y'(0)$. But you have not looked at $y'(0)$ at all. Therefore it remains to verify that  $y'(0)=0$ as well. The value $y'(0)$ cannot be computed by formal term-differentiation, since  the function $y(\cdot)$ is defined per exception handling at $0$. In order to compute $y'(0)$ you have to resort to the definition  of the derivative instead:
$$y'(0)=\lim_{x\to0}{y(x)-y(0)\over x-0}=\lim_{x\to0}{y(x)\over x}=\ldots\quad.$$

Comment: So you're saying I should do the definition of derivative first and then carry about a more rigorous proof? Or it's fine to just use the definition?

Comment: @Savage Henry: See my edit. You don't have to *define* the derivative; you have to *compute* the derivative at $0$, using the definition of derivative.

Comment: Yeah I didn't misinterpret that :) On the interval $(0,1]$, I evaluated using the definition of derivative so I had
$$y'(0)=\lim_{t \to \infty} \frac{x^3sin(\frac{\pi}{x})}{x}=\lim_{t \to \infty} x^2sin(\frac{\pi}{x})$$
and then I prove by Squeeze Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

The proof is correct; once you arrive at

> $$|3x^2|+\pi|x| = 3x^2+\pi x < 3x^2 + 4x,$$

you can directly use $3x^2 \leq 3x$ if $0<x\leq 1$; this allows you to write

$$ |3x^2|+\pi|x| = 3x^2+\pi x < 3x + \pi x = x(3+\pi) = |x|(3+\pi)$$

as $x$ is non negative. Choosing $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{3+\pi}$ you can end the proof, as well (maybe quicker).